# .gitignore files added inside Git submodules

Tags: git, vim, gitignore, git-submodules

I recently reorganized my dotfiles to live inside a Git repository at `~/Dropbox/dotfiles` and I'm using pathogen to bundle all Vim addons inside `~/Dropbox/dotfiles/home/.vim/bundle`. These addons were added as Git submodules.

Now the problem is, when I run Vim, it automatically generates the documentation for all addons and puts them inside each submodule directory. This adds untracked content to the submodules, which I'd like to avoid.

```
ruby-1.8.7-p330@gs ~/Dropbox/dotfiles ‹master*› $ git st
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   home/.vim/bundle/fuzzyfinder (untracked content)
#   modified:   home/.vim/bundle/l9 (untracked content)
#   modified:   home/.vim/bundle/matchit (untracked content)
#   modified:   home/.vim/bundle/ruby (untracked content)
#   ...
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I tried to add a `.gitignore` file to the root of my Git repository to ignore all `doc` folders inside submodules, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
home/.vim/bundle/**/doc
```

My question: is there a way to ignore files and folders inside Git submodules or maybe configure Vim to create the documentation in a folder outside the Git repository?

EDIT: as Randy Morris pointed out, this might be a duplicate of [Generating tags to different location by pathogen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343544/generating-tags-to-different-location-by-pathogen#4346300)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343544/generating-tags-to-different-location-by-pathogen#4346300

Comment: You're right. Going to flag the question. Thanks!

Comment: Note: `**` in `.gitignore` does not mean “at any depth”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: can I suppress listing of 'modified content'/dirty submodule entries in status, diff, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240881/git-can-i-suppress-listing-of-modified-content-dirty-submodule-entries-in-sta)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You should add `.gitignore` within each of your submodules.
Since said submodules are like nested Git repo, they take care of their own ignore rules, and their status wouldn't be influenced by the `.gitignore` of the parent repo (as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462754/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-git-submodules-over-having-a-repo-inside-another-r/1462775#1462775)).

For a vim-specific setting, as [Randy Morris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155299/randy-morris) mentions in the comment, see  the SO question "[Generating tags to different location by pathogen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343544/generating-tags-to-different-location-by-pathogen#4346300)".

---

Note: as [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959/nick) mentions in this comments, and as illustrated by the answer to "[Generating tags to different location by pathogen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343544/generating-tags-to-different-location-by-pathogen/4346300#4346300)", a config like:

```
[submodule "path/to/submodule"]
    path = path/to/submodule
    url = http://github.com/username/repo.git
    ignore = untracked  # <====
```

will work and make that submodule ignored by `git status`.
But "**`ignore = untracked`**" [means at least **Git1.7.2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240881/git-can-i-suppress-listing-of-modified-content-dirty-submodule-entries-in-stat/3241155#3241155).

The config is usually found in the `.git/` folder of your repo.

---

Note: [nurettin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227755/nurettin) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127178/gitignore-files-added-inside-git-submodules/5127213?noredirect=1#comment29277229_5127213):

> `ignore = dirty` did it for me

[Commit aee9c7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aee9c7d6540fe6f66fbbe7be420caa26ae0fa2d9) details the difference between `untracked` and `dirty`.

- "**`dirty`**": Only differences of the commit recorded in the superproject and the submodules `HEAD` will be considered modifications, **all changes to the work tree of the submodule will be ignored**.
  **When using this value, the submodule will not be scanned for work tree changes at all, leading to a performance benefit on large submodules**.
- "**`untracked`**": Only untracked files in the submodules work tree are ignored, a changed `HEAD` and/or modified files in the submodule will mark it as modified.

Comment: I don't like modifying other people's Git repositories, but the `ignore = untracked` option works just fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: You need git version 1.7.2 at least for the ignore = untracked settings to work. See the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343544/generating-tags-to-different-location-by-pathogen/4346300#4346300

Comment: `ignore = dirty` did it for me

Comment: @nurettin interesting. I have included the `dirty` value option in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 8):

VonC's recommendation of `ignore = untracked` works, but you have to make the change for every such submodule.

If you want to solve the problem once and for all, you can configure a global gitignore pattern on every git repo, by `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`, then just add `doc/tags` to $HOME/.gitignore_global.

See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files.

Answer (score 2):

Ben's answer is a good start. But for such specific ignore rule, I don't like the global setting.

Prefer local config for each submodule, and a centralized ignore file in submodule root repository:

```
cd .vim/bundle
echo "doc/tags" > .gitignore_submodules
git submodule foreach git config --local core.excludesfile "../.gitignore_submodules"
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the basic problem here is that you are trying to ignore a 'tracked' change. `.gitignore` ignores only 'untracked' changes to the repo. To verify you can modify some file in your repo (which tracked) and also add it to your `.gitignore` file. On doing `git status` you will see that the file is still listed as 'modified'. Your submodule repo's are also considered tracked by your main repo, hence simply adding a gitignore to the parent repo won't work. As othere suggested, either add `.gitignore` rules individual repo's or if you're using a recent git version, you can use the `git status --ignore-submodules`.

Comment: nope. those files are new and they are 'untracked'. sorry, but that doesn't help solving the problem.