# git submodules with modified and untracked content - why and how to remove it?

Tags: git

this is what my `git status`' result looks like:

```
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   vim/bundle/pathogen (modified content)
#   modified:   vim/bundle/sparkup (untracked content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

running `git diff vim` shows this:

```
diff --git a/vim/bundle/pathogen b/vim/bundle/pathogen
--- a/vim/bundle/pathogen
+++ b/vim/bundle/pathogen
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit fcf77f5101f3e589ce006c40ad3a0432735a05cf
+Subproject commit fcf77f5101f3e589ce006c40ad3a0432735a05cf-dirty
diff --git a/vim/bundle/sparkup b/vim/bundle/sparkup
--- a/vim/bundle/sparkup
+++ b/vim/bundle/sparkup
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 04a81b41f116a19184359a6f8685c192f5c36c70
+Subproject commit 04a81b41f116a19184359a6f8685c192f5c36c70-dirty
```

Why is the one untracked, the other modified, what does the diff mean? But most important: how did it happen and how to get rid of it?

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5127213/199649 evokes more option.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

One of the tracked files in `vim/bundle/pathogen` has been modified somehow.  There is also some untracked (and unignored) content in the submodule `vim/bundle/sparkup`.  In either case, the way to figure out what is modified / untracked is to change into the submodule directory and run `git status`.  (In the case of untracked files in a submodule, this is frequently a build product that has not been added to `.gitignore` in upstream.)

Comment: +1 seems obvious, but this stumped me for a bit.  My submodule was not ignoring anything, but the root repo was.

Answer (score 60):

Add `ignore = dirty` to each problematic `submodule` section in `.gitmodules` files placed at root of repo. Example:

```
[submodule "vim/bundle/nerdtree"]                                               
  path = vim/bundle/nerdtree                                                    
  url = https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git                              
  ignore = dirty
```

As seen at NilsH's [How to ignore changes in git submodules](http://www.nils-haldenwang.de/frameworks-and-tools/git/how-to-ignore-changes-in-git-submodules). Found thanks to [Synchronizing plugins with git submodules and pathogen](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/) vimcast.

Answer (score 27):

Head into the submodule's directory and make sure there isn't anything being built (an output of some kind) w/o you knowing.

```
cd submoduledir/
git status
```

If you see any untracked files in here, just do this to remove them:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -fxd
```

Comment: I found that even though the untracked files didn't actually exist on disk, Git seemed to be behaving as if they were. I don't know why this happened, but using the clean command as per your example worked.

Comment: Thank you for removing everything that was under .gitignore. Now my entire IDE configuration and vendor cache is gone... N.B. this will remove everything that is .gitignore'd

Comment: i like clean and fast solution :)

Comment: I tried your solution and got a `Skipping repository ...` exactly on the submodule which has the untracked changes

Comment: This worked for me. :) @MichaelYoo Dunno if an IDE should be littering a submodule with its configuration files... Good caution for those who use IDEs - but which one did this silly thing? :)

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same situation:

> gongzelong:shadowsocks-android gongzelong$ git status On branch master
>   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
>
> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add ..." to update
>   what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory)   (commit or discard the untracked or
>   modified content in submodules)
>
> ```
>     modified:   core/src/main/jni/badvpn (modified content)
>     modified:   core/src/main/jni/libancillary (modified content)
>     modified:   core/src/main/jni/libevent (modified content)
>     modified:   core/src/main/jni/redsocks (modified content)
>     modified:   core/src/overture/src/github.com/shadowsocks/overture (modified
> ```
>
> content)
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

When I git diff to see what is the changes:

```
gongzelong:shadowsocks-android gongzelong$ git diff
diff --git a/core/src/main/jni/badvpn b/core/src/main/jni/badvpn
--- a/core/src/main/jni/badvpn
+++ b/core/src/main/jni/badvpn
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 58f8a8883e51e5cb97391c4b6733ce255bf11f95
+Subproject commit 58f8a8883e51e5cb97391c4b6733ce255bf11f95-dirty
diff --git a/core/src/main/jni/libancillary b/core/src/main/jni/libancillary
--- a/core/src/main/jni/libancillary
+++ b/core/src/main/jni/libancillary
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 311e5d14f593f16c785bc6605220517eb1f21f6b
+Subproject commit 311e5d14f593f16c785bc6605220517eb1f21f6b-dirty
diff --git a/core/src/main/jni/libevent b/core/src/main/jni/libevent
--- a/core/src/main/jni/libevent
+++ b/core/src/main/jni/libevent
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit f29f07bc8c43eec96f227e6f6eede32b3af66168
+Subproject commit f29f07bc8c43eec96f227e6f6eede32b3af66168-dirty
diff --git a/core/src/main/jni/redsocks b/core/src/main/jni/redsocks
--- a/core/src/main/jni/redsocks
+++ b/core/src/main/jni/redsocks
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 274334f14839431ae003774d99c3d1de337afff4
+Subproject commit 274334f14839431ae003774d99c3d1de337afff4-dirty
diff --git a/core/src/overture/src/github.com/shadowsocks/overture b/core/src/overture/src/github.com/shadowsocks/overture
--- a/core/src/overture/src/github.com/shadowsocks/overture
+++ b/core/src/overture/src/github.com/shadowsocks/overture
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit a9b5a94e215c1beadfe11442994b550e1e81f8d6
+Subproject commit a9b5a94e215c1beadfe11442994b550e1e81f8d6-dirty
```

I fixed it like this:

> gongzelong:shadowsocks-android gongzelong$ git submodule update --init
>   gongzelong:shadowsocks-android gongzelong$ git submodule foreach git
>   reset --hard Entering 'core/src/main/jni/badvpn'
>
> HEAD is now at 58f8a88 Fix bug UDP checksum calculation. Entering
>   'core/src/main/jni/libancillary' HEAD is now at 311e5d1 Fix C++
>   building Entering 'core/src/main/jni/libev' HEAD is now at 5213419
>   Merge pull request #2 from Mygod/master Entering
>   'core/src/main/jni/libevent' HEAD is now at f29f07bc Update to 2.1.8
>   Entering 'core/src/main/jni/libsodium' HEAD is now at c5e43f4c Update
>   dotnet example version Entering 'core/src/main/jni/mbedtls' HEAD is
>   now at 4f0929189 Update version number to 2.6.1 Entering
>   'core/src/main/jni/pcre' HEAD is now at 222bbf4 Merge "pcre: silence
>   uninteresting warnings." am: 0e44fd55f8 Entering
>   'core/src/main/jni/redsocks' HEAD is now at 274334f Use standard
>   **ANDROID** preprocessor macro (#1) Entering 'core/src/main/jni/shadowsocks-libev' HEAD is now at 57e74ea Fix a bug
>   in bypassing Entering
>   'core/src/overture/src/github.com/shadowsocks/overture' HEAD is now at
>   a9b5a94 Format the source code gongzelong:shadowsocks-android
>   gongzelong$  gongzelong:shadowsocks-android gongzelong$ git status On
>   branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

Reference: [git-discard-submodule-changes](https://kalyanchakravarthy.net/blog/git-discard-submodule-changes/)

Answer (score 9):

If you're really sure you want to just do it (I'm managing vim bundles with pathogen and git submodules and some how I managed to get some tags folders in repos - and they just had to go) you can loop through submodules and remove untracked files.

```
cd YOUR_REPO_WITH_SUBMODULES/
git submodule foreach git clean -f -d
```

`-f` to force, `-d` to remove directories

You can check the docs here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

Comment: After running this I still have a submodule with "modified content"

Comment: @Peter git clean removes untracked files. Modified content on the other hand is not touched by git clean. To get rid of that you can do `git submodule update --checkout --recursive`

Comment: In my opinion the answer by @bloke_zero is the best one. No need to modify `.gitignore` or add "ignore dirty" to `.gitmodules`

Comment: I tried your solution and got a `Skipping repository ...` exactly on the submodule which has the untracked changes.

Answer (score 1):

As the author of pathogen states in the [FAQ](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#faq), you can ignore tags globally:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.cvsignore'
echo tags >> ~/.cvsignore
```