# project folder, that contains sub-folder with .git folder seems issue

Tags: git

all the files in the folder are adding except the following one, i dont know what the issue, i guess there is a .git folder is that something related.

[image]

[image]

There are files and folders in the dompdf-module, need to be added to the repo.

[image]

These was the response after i add the files from the folder dino/dompdf-module

[image]

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the deletion of the submodule approach: you can now read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

"`modified content`" means `dompdf-module` is the root folder of a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), which is like a kind of nested git repo with modifications of its own. A [diff should show it "dirty"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4874323/6309). You could [ignore that state if you wanted to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215013/6309).

You should:

- go in that folder and `git add -A .; git commit -m "modif in dompdf-module"`
- go back in the parent repo, and add and commit the new `dompdf-module` **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) which records the new SHA1 for that submodule)

Note: [after discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89396/discussion-between-user3929758-and-vonc), it appears that:

`git diff .` returns `Unable to create health/.git/index.lock`, which means the git process has somehow crashed.

Since that git is an old 1.9.5, I asked to upgrade to 2.5.2, in which case, there is no more "modified content" message, and everything seem clea.

Side note: the submodule has been cloned from an url not owned by the user. If any modification need to be done in it, the OP would need to fork that repo, and [change the url of the submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule).

Another approach is to **[delete the submodule, but keep it on the disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26752628/6309)**, then making it part of the main repo: no more nested `.git` folder.

Comment: but still my folder not adding files to the remote

Comment: @user3929758 did you add and commit within `dompdf-module`, and then add and comit in the parent folder of `dompdf-module`? When you are in that parent folder, what does a `git diff .` returns?

Comment: Unable to create health/.git/index.lock

Comment: @user3929758 what version of Git for widows are you using?

Comment: git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0 | Windows 8.1

Comment: @user3929758 can you try with git 2.5.2: no need for setup, just uncompress [PortableGit-2.5.2-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.2-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want and call `c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.5.2-64-bit\git-bash.exe`.

Comment: Update to latest, but still remains the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89396/discussion-between-user3929758-and-vonc).