# Git commit does not work even if I add, it's saying "Changes not staged for commit"

Tags: git, github, commit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh7HG.png)

First I cloned the repository and changed the file.
After I tried to add and commit but commit doesn't work

I tried to add --all add . add filename but doesn't work...

```
goott-1-13@goott-1-13-PC MINGW64 /e/workspaceWeb/web/WebContent/radarRelay (hwi-update)
$ git add .

goott-1-13@goott-1-13-PC MINGW64 /e/workspaceWeb/web/WebContent/radarRelay (hwi-update)
$ git commit -m "1"
On branch hwi-update
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   Token_Radar (modified content)

    no changes added to commit
```

this is the result when I try add --all , status

```
    goott-1-13@goott-1-13-PC MINGW64 /e/workspaceWeb/web/WebContent/radarRelay (hwi-update)
$ git add --all

goott-1-13@goott-1-13-PC MINGW64 /e/workspaceWeb/web/WebContent/radarRelay (hwi-update)
$ git status
On branch hwi-update
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   Token_Radar (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Is `Token_Rader` a file or a folder?

Comment: Please read [ask], and [please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Token_Rader is a folder

Comment: You could show us the output of `git add --all` and `git status` - might be helpful. Also `stat Token_Radar` and also the contents of `Token_Radar`. :)

Comment: Is `Token_Radar` an other git repository you added to your project?

Answer (score 1):

The words "modified content" in parentheses here:

> ```
> modified:   Token_Radar (modified content)
> ```

mean that `Token_Radar` is specifically a *submodule*.

It's a bit hard to describe what a submodule is without using analogies.  But the central essense of "submodule-ness" is that there's a *second, separate Git repository* involved here.  The Git repository you're working in has a *reference to* that other Git repository, but not a *copy of* that other Git repository.

What this means is that your Git, running in *your* repository, is merely reporting to you: *By the way, I can commit here and save everything, but what I'm saving and remembering is the hash ID of some commit in some other Git repository.  That's not what you have checked out in the work-tree of that other Git repository.  If you make a new clone of me later, I'll remember that I'm supposed to refer to commit `a123456...` in some other Git repository.  I can even clone that other Git repository for you, and go into it and have it check out commit `a123456...` again.  But when I do, what you'll get in my new submodule-clone-work-tree won't match what you have in your submodule-clone-work-tree right now.*

It's up to you to decide whether this is a normal, tolerable, and/or expected situation.  If *not*, you'll have to *enter the other Git repository*—go into the work-tree for the Git repository that is the submodule `Token_Radar`—and do something there.  What that *something* is depends on what you want to do about the situation.

You could go into that submodule, `git checkout` a branch there—submodules are usually not on any branch—and make a new commit in the submodule and then push the new commit to wherever the submodule comes from.<sup>1</sup>  Once you have done all that, you can then return to your superproject—the Git repository in which `Token_Radar` is a submodule—and `git add` the new commit hash.

That might not be what you want.  I can't predict what you want; only you can decide what you want.

See also [git submodules with modified and untracked content - why and how to remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7993413/1256452)  This other question, and most of its answers, are directed at the idea that the change in the submodule was accidental, and should be *discarded* rather than *saved*.

---

<sup>1</sup>In some cases, this might require that you first make a temporary commit or two, e.g., using `git stash`.  You might instead want to make a *new* branch, starting at the current commit, and then add a new commit at that new branch.  Again, much of this depends on what sort of outcome you desire—particularly, what you'd like to have happen tomorrow, or next month, or next year, when you may well have made all-new clones.  You'll have to predict what the future you wishes the present you had done, and do that now.

Answer (score -1):

If it's an empty folder put one file in it and then try to add -> commit this.

Git is file tracking version control system. 
Check this, good luck. [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: Why should a file that is permanently changing be a problem or result in that described behavior? The `git add` would stage the current changes of the file and the `git commit` would commit the stagged changes even if the file changes further.

Comment: `no changes added to commit` You are right I should edit me answer, thank you.