# Git ignore doesn't ignore the specified folders/files

Tags: git, gitignore

I want my .gitignore to ignore certain folders and files so I came up with the following:

```
*.class

# usual java ignores
bin/
.metadata

# Maven
*/target/*
target/*
/target/
*/deploy/*
deploy/*

# src-gen folder is populated by the command of protobuf, these files should not be pushed
src-gen/*

# eclipse generated stuff
dependency-reduced-pom.xml

# we shouldn't have .jar files in our repository, 
# apart from these 5 jars which are vital for our build process
*.jar
!/projectName/bundle/**/*.jar

# For Unix editors 
# sometimes make file copies ending
# with ~
# To ignore them use:
*~

# For Mac
.DS_Store
._*

# For markdown read me files
.README.md.html
```

However, after a `git status` I cannot see anything to be deleted as output. Note that this is a submodule, if that matters at all. And I want this `.gitignore` to ignore everything without specifying any folder name, since I don't want any hardcoding.

Here is the folder structure I have:

```
+ parentRepo
  + thisRepo
    + .gitignore
    + projectName
      + src-gen
      + target
      + deploy
      + dependency-reduced-pom.xml
      + bundle
        + system
          + 1.jar
          + 2.jar
          + 3.jar
          + 4.jar
          + 5.jar
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*"I cannot see anything to be deleted"* -- you just told `git` to ignore some files; now you expect it to delete them?

`.gitignore` is used only for files that are not already tracked (i.e when new files are added to the repository). If the file is already in the repository and you want `git` to ignore it then you have to remove it from the repository (`git rm --cached file`) and commit the change.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your `.gitignore` is in the root directory. In that directory run `git status` and copy the path to the file from the status output and paste it into the `.gitignore`.

`.gitignore` will only ignore files that you haven't already added to your repository.

Comment: So, I will have only 1 .gitignore (in the parent directory) and it will do everything for the submodules as well?

Comment: Yes, but make sure that the files you want to ignore,  you did not add the files already to the git repo.

Comment: [Some](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5127213/6533075) say differently about 1 `.gitignore` for all.

Comment: There can be multiple `.gitignore` files in any sub directories but the Best Practice is to have one `.gitignore` in a given projects root. Otherwise it is tricky to know "which" `.gitignore` file to look at to find something that's being ignored. Given that you can use patterns as file names that could be pretty tricky!

Answer (score 2):

so late but helpful!

i had the same problem with bin and obj folders!

i found i uploaded them before in my repository!

so i deleted them from repository and stashed all files, then synced with repo , the problem solved