# Ignore new commits for git submodule

Tags: git, status, git-submodules, ignore

## Background

Using Git 1.8.1.1 on Linux. The repository looks as follows:

```
master
  book
```

The submodule was created as follows:

```
$ cd /path/to/master
$ git submodule add https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git book
```

The `book` submodule is clean:

```
$ cd /path/to/master/book/
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

## Problem

The master, on the other hand, shows there are "new commits" for the book submodule:

```
$ cd /path/to/master/
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   book (new commits)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Git should ignore the submodule directory completely, so that the master is also clean:

```
$ cd /path/to/master/
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

## Failed Attempt #1 - dirty

Inside the file `master/.gitmodules` is the following, as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542452/59087):

```
[submodule "book"]
        path = book
        url = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
        ignore = dirty
```

## Failed Attempt #2 - untracked

Changed `master/.gitmodules` to the following, as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127213/59087):

```
[submodule "book"]
        path = book
        url = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
        ignore = untracked
```

## Failed Attempt #3 - showUntrackedFiles

Edited `master/.git/config` to the following, as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345788/59087):

```
[status]
   showUntrackedFiles = no
```

## Failed Attempt #4 - ignore

Added the book directory to the master ignore file:

```
$ cd /path/to/master/
$ echo book > .gitignore
```

## Failed Attempt #5 - clone

Added the book directory to the master as follows:

```
$ cd /path/to/master/
$ rm -rf book
$ git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git book
```

## Question

How can the `book` submodule be in its own repository directory under the `master` repository yet have git ignore the `book` submodule? That is, the following should not display:

```
#
#       modified:   book (new commits)
#
```

How to suppress that message when executing `git status` in the master repository?

An article about [git submodule pitfalls](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/) suggests this an inappropriate submodule usage?

Comment: You normally use submodules if you want to link the repository to a certain version of another repository, and keep track of that. But that does not seem what you want to to. You just want to use a repository inside another one, without tracking it. Don't add it as a submodule then.

Comment: @FelixKling, if you add such repos that way and push it to GitHub, would it create just link for it without copying content of that folders?

Comment: @Roland: Submodules are just files with a reference to the version of an other repository. Once they are initialized in a local copy of the repository, they are replaced by the actual content of the repository.

Comment: I think you are looking for "ignore = all"

Comment: With Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), you will be able to consider `git config submodule.<name>.active false`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43440263/6309)

Comment: @VonC does not work for submodules that are already checked out.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To include another repository, that needn't be tracked in its super-repo, try this:

```
$ cd /path/to/master/
$ rm -rf book
$ git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git book
$ git add book
$ echo "book" >> .gitignore
```

Then commit.

As stated in the linked [git submodule pitfalls article](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/):

> ... the only linkage between the parent and the submodule is [the] recorded value of the submodule’s checked-out SHA which is stored in the parent’s commits.

That means that a submodule is not saved by its checked-out branch or tag, but always by a specific commit; that commit (SHA) is saved into the super-repo (the one containing the submodule) like a normal text file (it's marked as such a reference, of course).

When you check out a different commit *in the submodule* or make a new commit in it, the super-repo will see that its checked out SHA has changed. That's when you get the `modified (new commits)` line from `git status`.

To eliminate that, you can either:

- `git submodule update`, which will reset the submodule to the commit currently saved in the super-repo (for details see [the `git submodule` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule); or
- `git add book && git commit` to save the new SHA into the super-repo.

As mentioned in the comments, consider abandoning the `book` submodule: clone it inside the super-repo, if tracking of its state as part of the super-repo is not necessary.

Comment: Wow, now I understand, *why* the supermodule needs to know the version of the submodule. Of course, it makes sense to do `git add book && git commit`. I did not realize that git can actually ensure that the two repos are in sync.

Answer (score 123):

Just run:

```
$ git submodule update
```

This will revert the submodule the to old commit (specified in parent-repo), without updating the parent-repo with the latest version of the submodule.

Comment: No it's not, it won't change the status.

Comment: Why exactly would OP want to **not** have the latest from the `book` repository? I don't think your answer makes any sense in this context.

Comment: @AlexisWilke and if book interface change dramatically and OP don't have time to make changes in master repo?

Comment: can you do this while you're fixing conflicts during a merge?

Answer (score 24):

There are two kinds of change notices you can suppress (from git 1.7.2).

The first is untracked content which happens when you make changes to your submodule but have not yet committed those. The parent repository notices these and git status reports it accordingly:

```
modified: book (untracked content)
```

You can suppress these with :

```
[submodule "book"]
    path = modules/media
    url = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
    ignore = dirty
```

However, once you commit those changes, the parent repository will once again take notice and report them accordingly:

```
modified:   book (new commits)
```

If you want to suppress these too, you need to ignore all changes

```
[submodule "book"]
    path = book
    url = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
    ignore = all
```

Comment: Imagine I've added `ignore = all` option to all submodules. Eventually some modules has new commits that was pushed. If somebody then clone super-repo, will it be on the old state of submodules or it will checkout the latest ones?

Comment: With the command ```git clone --recursive git@...``` you will get the old state of the submodules. To update them, you will need something like ```git submodule foreach "git pull"``` after cloning

Comment: Unfortunately, `ignore = all` option doesn't ignore the new commits of the submodule. I am running git version 1.7.1. Any idea way?

Comment: I like this fix method

Comment: @FelikZ
`git submodule foreach --recursive "git pull --rebase" `
`git submodule foreach --recursive "git checkout xxxBranch"`

Answer (score 12):

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) will add another way to include a submodule which does not need to be tracked by its parent repo.

In the OP's case:

```
git config submodule.<name>.active false
```

See [commit 1b614c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b614c07d2428927358cc7317622913d1dbd59c9), [commit 1f8d711](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f8d711548c08e05766e067dc23e5be3b1b72657), [commit bb62e0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb62e0a99fcbb9ceb03502bf2168d2e57530214f), [commit 3e7eaed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e7eaed016e6241e96de6a0140923e81cfc387e8), [commit a086f92](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a086f921a725319a6f0c2c3aacf676c890b3ce3e) (17 Mar 2017), and [commit ee92ab9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee92ab992fada00ca945bddce5c281ca0927747c), [commit 25b31f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25b31f1b73331d3d9e90a72c34e514795e98c174), [commit e7849a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7849a9677e9db6af81f568ae40ad2eddf5d3f0d), [commit 6dc9f01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dc9f01f33bdbaebcf811c89766d4e4902a96f27), [commit 5c2bd8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c2bd8b77aeefa4c6484684ef3e9227a6287a93e) (16 Mar 2017) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a93dcb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a93dcb0a56a38289632a85d906e49150b1e34100), 30 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### `submodule`: decouple url and submodule interest
>
> Currently the `submodule.<name>.url` config option is used to determine if
>   a given submodule is of interest to the user.  This ends up being
>   cumbersome in a world where we want to have different submodules checked
>   out in different worktrees or a more generalized mechanism to select
>   which submodules are of interest.
>
> In a future with worktree support for submodules, there will be multiple
>   working trees, each of which may only need a subset of the submodules
>   checked out.
>   The URL (which is where the submodule repository can be obtained) should not differ between different working trees.
>
> It may also be convenient for users to more easily specify groups of
>   submodules they are interested in as opposed to running "`git submodule init <path>`" on each submodule they want checked out in their working
>   tree.
>
> To this end two config options are introduced, `submodule.active` and
>   `submodule.<name>.active`.
>
> - The `submodule.active` config holds a pathspec that specifies which submodules should exist in the working tree.
>
>   - The `submodule.<name>.active` config is a boolean flag used to indicate if
>       that particular submodule should exist in the working tree.
>
> Its important to note that `submodule.active` functions differently than
>   the other configuration options since it takes a pathspec.
>   This allows users to adopt at least two new workflows:
>
> 1. Submodules can be grouped with a leading directory, such that a pathspec e.g. '`lib/`' would cover all library-ish modules to allow those who are interested in library-ish modules to set "`submodule.active = lib/`" just once to say any and all modules in '`lib/`' are interesting.
> 2. Once the pathspec-attribute feature is invented, users can label submodules with attributes to group them, so that a broad pathspec with attribute requirements, e.g. '`:(attr:lib)`', can be used to say any and all modules with the '`lib`' attribute are interesting.
>      Since the `.gitattributes` file, just like the `.gitmodules` file, is tracked by the superproject, when a submodule moves in the superproject tree, the project can adjust which path gets the attribute in `.gitattributes`, just like it can adjust which path has  the submodule in `.gitmodules`.

Comment: How to find the exact `<name>` for a sub-module in an existing project?

Comment: @ideasman42 Reading the config in the .gitmodules should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12641787/6309

Comment: Ah it's just the value from `.git/config` --> `[submodule "<name>"]`

Comment: Not work for me.  Here is what I do:
1) git clone with --recursive;
2) set git config as answer;
3) do git checkout, git pull  to checkout last submodule;
Still get  "(new commits)" .

Comment: @WuBaiquan What Git version are you using, on which OS?

Comment: @VonC,  I am using git version 2.15.1 on Mac.
git config -l "submodule.build_config.active=false" git status "modified:   build_config (new commits)"

Comment: @WuBaiquan OK: it is best to ask a separate question, then, to study a bit more that particular case.

Comment: @VonC I am using latest git version, and I did as you said. I opened the super-repository config file located in its .git folder and edited active = true to active = false. But still the changes to submodule can be committed and then it shows that the super-repository is dirty (and can be committed). Thus I am unable to ignore the commits from submodule.

Comment: @Nikhil Yes, re-reading https://github.com/git/git/commit/a93dcb0a56a38289632a85d906e49150b1e34100, I believe this would not work for existing submodules already checked out, but at the initial checkout of the parent repo, as in https://github.com/git/git/commit/a93dcb0a56a38289632a85d906e49150b1e34100#diff-af8cbc99c62622be5ef8516171e24893R1172.

Comment: @VonC Before messaging to you, I tried both (with existing repo as well as new initialized repo) , for both cases it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Nevik Rehnel answer is certainly the correct one for what you are asking: *I did not want to have a submodule, how the heck do I get out of that situation?!*.

Only, if your `master` project requires the `book` submodule, it is a nice gesture to keep it as such because that way other users who checkout your project can then enjoy not having any special `git` command to run (well... there are some special commands to use submodules, but it still simpler to manage, overall, I think.)

In your case you make changes in the `book` repository and at some point you commit those changes. This means you have *new commits* in that submodule, which have a new SHA1 reference.

What you need to do in the master directory is commit those changes in the master repository.

```
cd /path/to/master
git commit . -m "Update 'book' in master"
```

This will updated the SHA1 reference in `master` to the newest version available in the `book` repository. As a result this commit allows others to checkout all of the `master` & `book` repositories at the tip.

So in effect you end up with one more commit whenever you make changes to a submodule. It is semi-transparent if you also make changes to some files in the `master` repository since you'd commit both at the same time.

Answer (score -6):

Run

```
git submodule update
```

at the root level.

Comment: Just for anyone wondering.  In my case (and OPs?), this doesn't change what `git status` says.  It still thinks changes have happened.

Comment: It is very bad practice to clone other's answers