# How to only update specific git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

So, updating all my submodules is done by running

```
git submodule foreach 'git pull origin master'
```

How do I update a **specific submodule**, located in say `bundle/syntastic`, without updating any other submodules?

Comment: With Git .213 (Q2 2017), you will be able to consider `git clone --recurse-submodules="bundle/syntastic"`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43441315/6309).

Comment: @VonC : this checkout the submodule version linked, it doesnot upated it to HEAD  of master as `git submodule foreach 'git pull origin master'` does.

Comment: @mpromonet Good point: there was a config setting missing in [my (now edited) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43441315/6309.

Answer (score 101):

I end up there by searching how to update specific submodule only, which means for me, updating a submodule to the ref pointed by its super-repo.
Which is not the question nor the answer but only the title.

So in a hope of helping some others like me the answer to the question title is :

```
git submodule update <specific path to submodule>
```

which will put this submodule in the state of the ref commited in the super-repo.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, but (as mentioned) this is not an answer to the OP. Maybe someone with more power than me could  transform this into an answer to the right question (and possibly change the title of this question to prevent confusion).

Comment: For anyone who it may help: this accepts multiple paths, if you want to update multiple submodules in one go. `--depth 1` is nice too if you don't need the full history of that submodule, it gets only the needed commit.

Answer (score 60):

From the [git submodule documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

> --remote    This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the
>   status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch. The remote used is
>   branch’s remote (branch..remote), defaulting to origin.

In order to update a specific submodule you can use :

```
git submodule update --remote <path to the submodule>
```

In your case, it should be :

```
git submodule update --remote bundle/syntastic
```

Comment: The order matters BTW. Ie, this will NOT work: `git submodule update <path to the submodule> --remote`

Comment: It also seems to matter from where you run it. Eg, if you're dealing with a repo that has nested submodules, you need to execute this from the directory that uses the submodule you're trying to target, not within or outside of it regardless of absolute pathing.

Answer (score 43):

Actually the proper syntax is:

```
$ git clone <remote.git>
$ cd <remote>
$ git submodule update --init -- <specific relative path to submodule>
```

Answer (score 26):

If you've just cloned a repo with submodules, you can clone a specific submodule with:

`git submodule update --init submoduleName`

This will clone the version of that submodule from the repo reference, from there you can cd into the submodule and pull whatever branches you need.

Comment: This command clone the version of the submodule referenced by the repo, it doesnot update the submodule with its HEAD of master.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I update a specific submodule, located in say `bundle/syntastic`, without updating any other submodules?

With Git 2.13 (and the help of [`submodule.<name>.update` config setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-customcommand)):

```
git clone --recurse-submodules="bundle/syntastic"
git config submodule.syntastic.update "git pull origin master"
```

The second line (to be executed only once) is needed because the [`clone --recurse-submodules[=<pathspec]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspec) command is equivalent to running `git submodule update --init --recursive <pathspec>` immediately after the clone is finished.
And that would only checkout the submodule at its gitlink recorded SHA1, *not* at the latest remote `origin/master` SHA1.
By adding the [`submodule.<name>.update` config setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-submoduleltnamegtupdate), you ensure that the selective clone of the submodule will be followed by an update, only for that submodule.

---

As part of the Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) "active submodule" feature (see "[Ignore new commits for `git submodule`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440263/6309)"), you have this [commit bb62e0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb62e0a99fcbb9ceb03502bf2168d2e57530214f) from [Brandon Williams (`bmwill`)](https://github.com/bmwill):

> ### `clone`: teach `--recurse-submodules` to optionally take a pathspec
>
> Teach clone `--recurse-submodules` to optionally take a pathspec argument
>   which describes which submodules should be recursively initialized and
>   cloned.
>   If no pathspec is provided, `--recurse-submodules` will recursively initialize and clone all submodules by using a default pathspec of "`.`".
>   In order to construct more complex pathspecs, `--recurse-submodules` can be given multiple times.
>
> This also configures the '`submodule.active`' configuration option to be
>   the given pathspec, such that any future invocation of `git submodule
>   update` will keep up with the pathspec.
>
> Additionally the switch '`--recurse`' is removed from the Documentation as
>   well as marked hidden in the options array, to streamline the options
>   for submodules.  A simple '`--recurse`' doesn't convey what is being
>   recursed, e.g. it could mean directories or trees (c.f. `ls-tree`).
>   In a lot of other commands we already have '`--recurse-submodules`' to mean
>   recursing into submodules, so advertise this spelling here as the
>   genuine option.

So the [`git clone --recursive` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bb62e0a99fcbb9ceb03502bf2168d2e57530214f/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L218-L229) now reads:

```
--recurse-submodules[=<pathspec]:
```

> **After the clone is created, initialize and clone submodules within based on the provided pathspec**.
>
> If no pathspec is provided, all submodules are initialized and cloned.
>
> Submodules are initialized and cloned using their default settings.
>   The resulting clone has `submodule.active` set to the provided pathspec, or "`.`" (meaning all submodules) if no pathspec is provided.
>   This is equivalent to running `git submodule update --init --recursive` immediately after the clone is finished. This option is ignored if the cloned
>   repository does not have a worktree/checkout (i.e. if any of
>   `--no-checkout`/`-n`, `--bare`, or `--mirror` is given)

Example from the [`t/t7400-submodule-basic.sh` test](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bb62e0a99fcbb9ceb03502bf2168d2e57530214f/t/t7400-submodule-basic.sh#L1205-L1219):

```
git clone --recurse-submodules="." \
          --recurse-submodules=":(exclude)sub0" \
          --recurse-submodules=":(exclude)sub2" \
          multisuper multisuper_clone
```

That would clone and update every submodules, except `sub0` and `sub2`.

---

Bonus, with Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) "`git clone --recurs`" works better.

See [commit 5c38742](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c387428f10c27c24d3adb890cd466e2300518fa) (29 Apr 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2cfab60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cfab6087790ceeb81eb91eeb1300500cfa4c948), 19 May 2019)</sup>

> ### `parse-options`: don't emit "ambiguous option" for aliases
>
> Change the option parsing machinery so that e.g. "`clone --recurs ...`"
>   doesn't error out because "`clone`" understands both "`--recursive`" and
>   "`--recurse-submodules`" to mean the same thing.
>
> Initially "clone" just understood --recursive until the
>   `--recurses-submodules` alias was added in ccdd3da ("`clone`: Add the
>   `--recurse-submodules` option as alias for `--recursive`",
>   2010-11-04, Git v1.7.4-rc0).
>   Since [bb62e0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb62e0a99fcbb9ceb03502bf2168d2e57530214f) ("`clone`: teach `--recurse-submodules` to
>   optionally take a pathspec", 2017-03-17, Git v2.13.0-rc0) the longer form has been
>   promoted to the default.
>
> But due to the way the options parsing machinery works this resulted
>   in the rather absurd situation of:
>
> ```
> $ git clone --recurs [...]
> error: ambiguous option: recurs (could be --recursive or --recurse-submodules)
> ```
>
> Add `OPT_ALIAS()` to express this link between two or more options and use
>   it in git-clone.

Comment: this checkout the submodule version linked, it doesnot upated it to HEAD  of master as `git submodule foreach 'git pull origin master'` does.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked best for me is as follows:

```
git submodule --recursive --remote <path-to-submodule-directory>
```

I found this solution upon reading this very useful [article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/git-pull-submodule)