# Managing a git with sub repositories

Tags: git, github

I'm putting together a git repo with a bunch of code and have noticed that much of the code I'm wanting to be available in my repo is available from other Git sources. I have done quite a bit of reading on the submodules and subtrees, but not I'm sure which fits my use case the best.

My git repo will have a number of folders, scripts, etc and I want to have the latest code from the remote repositories.

Ideally, if either myself or someone in the community wants to make and change and submit a patch for the code in a folder that is under remote git control, they could work under that folder and submit the patch without effecting my repo.

I also want user to be able to submit patches to my repo for scripts/files without causing a lot of heartache due to submodules/subtrees, etc.

Recommendation on the preferred solution?  Submodules, subtrees, or something else?

Here is the example layout.

Folder1

---------SubFolder1.1

Folder2 <= Git Repo =>

Folder3

---------SubFolder3.1   <= Git Repo =>

Answer (score 2):

> much of the code I'm wanting to be available in my repo is available from other Git sources
>   I want to have the latest code from the remote repositories.

Submodule seems the best fit, espacially since [a submodule can follow the latest commits from a given branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20114699/6309).
but since you want to submit patches, that means you must first:

- fork a repository
- add the fork as a submodule to your project.

That way, you can:

- create a dedicated branch within that submodule,
- make new commits
- push those to your fork
- make a pull request from there

The only complexity with submodule is to remember that any modification within a submodule means you have to go back to the parent repo, add, commit and push the new SHA1 of the [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) representing your modified submodule.