# Teamcity - Multiple web project in a single repo - deploy only some of them

Tags: git, teamcity, webdeploy

I have a git repo which contains a single .Net solution with several web applications (public site, internal site, public services) and a shared class library project. I want to deploy some of the projects based on the changes that were made. For example if I fixed a bug in public site I want to only deploy that site, if I fixed bug in public site and api I want to deploy both of them and so on. I can achieve it by creating different build configurations and using trigger rule and filter by [Ant_like_wildcard](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules) folder path and deploy corresponding project.

The tricky case in when I make a change only in a shared class library but not in any of the web apps. In that case I have the following options:

- Make a dummy change in the web apps which must be deployed
- Include web projects which must be deployed in commit message and use [VCS_comment_regexp](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules) for filtering triggers
- Parse git commit message, set parameters using [setParameter](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter) in build script and use those parameters in following steps.

I don't like any of the options because they seem hacky. Is there any better option for this case?

Comment: Can you change the filter on the trigger rule for each build configuration to include both the web application and the shared library folders?

Comment: @tspauld That won't work because making a change in shared library does not necessarily mean that I want to deploy all web apps.

Comment: @tspauld said what I was thinking. So, what does determine which web apps should be deployed if only the shared library changes? You haven't told us that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shared class library project is referenced as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of the three other webapps, that means each webapp can chose to update to the latest commit of that shared lib project repo.

That would cause the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (the [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309) of a parent repo) to change, which would in turn make the parent repo register a new commit (referencing the new gitlink SHA1 of the submodule repo)
That would no longer be a "dummy change".
And that would be picked up by TeamCity as a webapp new change triggering the job.

Comment: I guess this is the correct approach but will it complicate day to day workflow for developers? For example if I work on a new feature which needs changes in web app and shared library will I need to a separate branch in both repos?

Comment: @Giorgi no, no separate branch needed. But if any change is made in webapp, you need to make sure that a `git add && git commit` is done at the parent repo level (which would be done anyway if the feature changes also the parent repo files): the gitlink needs to be recorded.

Comment: So I would need to create a branch only in the parent repo?

Comment: @Giorgi my bad: you do need to create two branches, one for each repo. I was thinking initially about two different *names*: you can call those two branches with the same name here.

Comment: @Giorgi don't forget you can set up a submodule to follow a branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20016830/6309

Answer (score 0):

There are few options:

1. As mentioned above use **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** or **[subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/)**.
2. Use git **[hooks](http://play.elevatorsaga.com/documentation.html)** to "capture" the desired branch (folder/file/path  whatever you need) and execute any build/deploy script that you want to execute.
   If you use git hub there are much more options. Git hub named those: **[webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)**

for example:
`git diff-tree -r --name-only HEAD^1` will give you list of all modified files in the current commit. use it with grep to search for your required path.

Hope it helped you to solve your problem.