# Git submodule init to HEAD instead of specific commit

Tags: git, git-submodules

In my project I have a git submodule tracking the repo `B`.
When the repo is cloned on a new machine, the git sobmodule seems to track a specific commit, so when new commits are done in the repo `B` I have to manually do a pull on main repo, and then commit it, otherwise new clones of the repo will ends up having the submodule to the old commit of the repo `B`, is this the normal behavior? Can I make the sobmodule track the `HEAD` instead of a specific commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git submodule to track remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986075/git-submodule-to-track-remote-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+track+branch

Comment: The short answer: no, whatever you do is the right and the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal and expected behavior. Basically, you want to always a predictible state in your working directory after a clone. If the repo B is updated, you have to manually fetch and merge these updates, then test it still works well with your main repo A, and then you can commit on repo A the information "submodule is now on commit XXX".

This avoid unwanted behavior if changes were performed on repo B that you didn't notice. If the submodule were always pointing on "latest commit", you couldn't be sure your project A is always in sync with submodule B.

Comment: I did import repo B just for test that it works with my component A :(