# Have multiple .Net / NetCore solutions in a single repo in github

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, github, repository

I hope not to overwhelm you with a question that you may have already asked before, but after trying different solutions, I have not obtained good results.

Basically, what I am trying to solve is the following: I have created a repository in my GitHub account, now I have three solutions, one is a net-core console app, the other is an mvcCore app and finally an API.

I want to add each of these solutions in the repository that I create on GitHub but in an orderly way that is to say that each solution is in a "sub-folder"

Comment: Do you need to have three solutions? It's common to have related projects in the same solution. Do these projects reference each other in any way?

Comment: Yes they do, in fact I have two more mvcCore solutions I would need to add

Comment: I general I would prefer to have a separate repo for each solution since they are essentially independent (at least, that's what solutions are supposed to be, as far as I know). But if it suits you better, I don't see any obvious reason why it would not work to have each solution and its related project files each in a subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage each of your solutions in their own respective GitHub repositories, then you could reference them in a common parent repository (the one you have initially created) as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

You can even declare those [submodules to follow their own branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309), which means a [simple `git submodule update --init --remote`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016830/6309) would update their content to the latest commit of their respective branch.