# Git - How to pull specific one of the submodules version

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-submodules, git-pull

For pull all the submodules from the master branch I'm using this command.

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

How can I pull only one submodule from specific branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to only update specific git submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728866/how-to-only-update-specific-git-submodules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `cd` into the location of the submodule that you want to update and then do a `git pull origin master` from there.

That will only update the one submodule. You can then check in the updated code.