# GitLab showing modified folders instead of files

Tags: git, github, gitlab

We are using git for source control using GitLab. The problem is, I created a new branch with no uncommitted files in the repository from where i created the branch and it is showing the modified folder and not files as follows,

```
# On branch 114531
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   lib/library/CL (new commits)
#   modified:   lib/library/FW (new commits)
#   modified:   plugins/CPP (new commits, modified content)
#   modified:   plugins/CRBP (new commits)
#   modified:   plugins/CUP (new commits)
#   modified:   plugins/SLP (new commits)
#   modified:   plugins/SIP (new commits)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What is actually wrong? Why i'm not seeing files and only seeing folders? And how to make it to show all the modified files instead of folder? Please help friends.

Comment: How did you create the branch?

Comment: @NikhilGupta By using the command "git branch 114531"

Comment: and how did you checkout the new branch?

Comment: @NikhilGupta Using "git checkout 114531"

Answer (score 2):

> why i'm not seeing files and only seeing folders?

Because those are **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** entries which reports new commits.

If you have done new commits in those submodule, you should push those, and go back to the parent repo (the one where you currently are), add those submodule entries (`git add .`), commit and push.

A `git submodule update` would reset those submodule to their original state.

See more at "[Ignore new commits for `git submodule`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14422494/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

I believe all these folders were marked as modified before you created the branch and you chose not to reset those changes when you checked out the new branch (`git checkout --force <branchname>` would have removed the modified content from the new branch)