# Git: how to unstage file changes (new commits)

Tags: git, github, version-control

```
mohamed@mohamed:~/Projects/skyrocket$ git status 
On branch dev/SMMWEB-36
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   config/puppet/modules/apt (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/augeas (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/concat (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/elasticsearch (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/file_concat (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/git (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/php (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/postgresql (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/redis (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/stdlib (new commits)
    modified:   config/puppet/modules/vcsrepo (new commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .idea/copyright/
    config/puppet/modules/blackfire/
    config/puppet/modules/inifile/
    dump.rdb
    keys.dev.pub
    keys.tags.pub

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I do not know what (new commits) does mean?
I do not want to commit these files.
I tried to do

```
$ git checkout -- .
```

What if i put config/puppet/* to gitignore file then updated the cache as following

```
$ git rm --cached -r .
```

will this delete these files from repo. after pushing or merging with other branches?

Answer (score 0):

`git reset` is the command to unstage file from git.

After unstaging the file, you can confirm it by `git status` command as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the directories under `config/puppet/modules/` are submodules, try

```
$ git submodule update
```

which worked for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14422494/5794048

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the modification for later use, just stash them with

`git add . && git stash save "info for the modification"`.

If you want to drop the modification, just do

`git add . && git reset --hard HEAD`

---

Attach:
  to show what you have stashed with `git stash list`, to apply the stash with `git stash pop`

Answer (score -1):

Use `git reset`  to unstage files !

Comment: How does this differ from existing answers mentioning `reset`?

Answer (score -1):

With "git reset" you can undo all adds
or with git reset file_name you can undo picked add

Answer (score -1):

We can run command `git reset --hard`

Comment: There should be no space between `--` and `hard`, as in [`--hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---hard). Otherwise it gets treated as [`git reset -- <path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt-emgitresetem-qlttree-ishgt--ltpathsgt82308203).