# How to commit to a git repo ignoring changes to submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

When I run `git commit -a` I would like it to skip committing changes to submodules.

*(incase it matters, I want to have the latest version of all submodules but not commit these changes to the remote git repository).*

How can this be done locally, so I can update submodules, but not commit changes to them?

So this works for eg:

```
git submodule foreach git origin master
```

---

Note that this seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418352/), but there seems some slight difference and the accepted answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the setting [`diff.ignoreSubmodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-diffignoreSubmodules) would help

```
 cd /path/to/my/repo
 git config diff.ignoreSubmodules all
```

Then a add+commit should only include files of the main repo.